# Why My question was closed, [Reopened] [RECLOSED again]?

Tags: support, specific-question, close-reasons, re-open

In my question I ask for practical tips for the mathematical research practice, if not personal,I look for some articles/websites/books/guides/faq related, or if was already asked on Math.SE, the link to the question.

[Practical Tips: Mathematical research and discoveries](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/386520/practical-tips-research-and-discoveries)

the motivation of the closure was this.

> "As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A
>   format. We expect answers to be supported by facts (1), references, or
>   specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate (2),
>   arguments, polling, or extended discussion(3). If you feel that this
>   question can be improved and possibly reopened"

(1) Why is not supported by facts? Is a pratical problem, and I'm asking for tips.

(2) I'm asking for a list of links/books not for opinions.

(3) I don't want do discuss the answers.

Another reason was:" Please see the FAQ about what questions are appropriate to ask here"

and in the faqs I read:

> You should only ask **practical**, **answerable** questions based on **actual problems that you face.**

The question is about **mathematical practice.**
Well, If someone do mathematical research or know some books/guides/related questions, than he can **answer** this question. And this is an **actual problem that I face.**

So where is the problem?

Thanks in advance

**QUESTION IS RECLOSED AGAIN!?**

Comment: Note that the question discussed has now been re-opened.

Comment: The thing is that it's an "actual problem" in academia, not in mathematics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I imagine people voted to close since the question would be seen by many to be off topic, I think that it is certainly borderline.

However, I think that it is valid and appropriate for the site. Most questions are related to specific mathematical problems, in the sense of proving things or answering questions, and so people forget that questions about how to undertake mathematics in a more general sense are also on topic. We have certainly had many in the past that have been well received.

One thing to bear in mind is that when people vote to close a question, they have to pick the "best available" reason to close. Thus the reason given may contain points that are not valid to a particular question (and at times even seem completly unrelated, although this is a different issue.)

Comment: In fact long ago I saw a very similar question with many interesting answer in math.SE (but not exatly the same), I tried to find it for 2 days but I was not able to remember the title. Ok thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 4):

I cast the fifth re-open vote (and thus has been re-opened).  Seems like a reasonable enough question to me.  There seems to be one answer in the comments already.

Note that, in order to close a question, merely 5 close votes are required.  From this, we cannot deduce that there is a consensus for closing.  We can only deduce that from the community (with a diverse range of opinions of what's good and what's not for the site) there are 5 people who have the ability to vote to chose, and voted for this particular question.

The reasons for closure can be varied, and the real reason can be quite dissimilar from the reason the software makes us choose (and each voter might have their own distinct reason, etc.).

Comment: I made a mistake by not trying to close as "off topic". There is nothing in the question special to mathematics. It could be asked in *any* research field, and so it is off topic and should go to academia.stackexchange.

Comment: yea Now I understand, anyways in the comments @rschwieb 's one was inded interesting, and I did not know the existence of accademia.SE, so thanks for the information.

Comment: @MphLee Sorry to come off as trying to shut you down :) I had another thing in mind but didn't express it well.